# CSS grid empty cell issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

I'm trying to understand the nature of css grid, im somewhat new to it. I want to keep my grid items responsive and maintain the aspect ratio of the images. It seems that there is a weird gap on the bottom of the images.

I look at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259136/remove-empty-space-in-css-grid) that could be similar, still not sure.

here is what i have

https://codepen.io/eliowl/pen/EOgNQe

**html**

```
<section id="about" class="about">
    <h3 class="text-center">About</h3>
    <section class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item --width3 ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541807084-5c52b6b3adef?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0c64fc542895cda41529f98ed3808572&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item --width ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541773477186-4133e93eb70e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=da73715faa685433b42f4decb9f71a60&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item --width2 ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541787975442-d5085a8ec678?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f6fc603cb3c4886ec55a1bff07ee7b53&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item   ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541780050666-f64773a3d779?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=9ce82bea4ecf5b343e5317a683fd8226&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="">
        </div>  


        <div class="grid-item  ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541766029309-8d7fa5bb773b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f3d1bf633d2a601dd04a716acfce40be&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
        </div>              

    </section>
</section>
```

**scss**

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    max-width: 1300px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;

    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
}

.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
align-items:flex-start;
    grid-column: auto / span 2;
    grid-row: auto / span 4;



     img {
        width: 100%;
    }

}

.--width{
      grid-row: 2;
}


.--width2{
     grid-row: auto / span 4;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or a jsfiddle with the issue?

Comment: ok, i updated it.

Comment: The main problem is coming from `align-items: flex-start`. Remove that rule, and the gaps are gone. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQzoXo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: You are trying to achieve something like this? https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/GwjNYo

Comment: @Michael_B it works, but its not responsive though.

Comment: @Michael_B yes thats what im looking to achieve, how did u do it ?

Comment: this looks good, now i probably want some flexibility with different size boxes and stuff that are still responsive. I will figure this out.

Comment: I commented the changes in the revised codepen. Also take a look at the link I posted.

Comment: yeah i saw it, it solves the problem. thanks michael :)